# Is it possible to install Tor Browser on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, install, tor

I recently brought an 10.5" iPad Pro that runs mainly on cellular data. I bought this device to travel with my husband over the road in his semi truck.

1. I have not been able to choose the right Tor browser to download. I tried the version for iOS/macOS which it did download; however I was not able to open the downloaded file no matter what I did.
2. Is it even possible to run Tor Browser on my iPad with Cellular Data?

What is going wrong and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding you correctly you are trying to download the macOS version of TorBrowser on your iPad?

If that is correct, that will never work. The *only place to download/install/buy applications for iOS devices* is the App Store which is itself an app on your iPad.

If you want a good Tor Browser on your iPad I use one called "Onion Browser" that seems to do the trick. Just search the App Store for that name and it will pop up. There are likely others that will doo a decent job too, but that is a good place to start.

Comment: I did as you suggested. I am on a page that says “Congatulations, This Browser is configured to use Tor.” Then below that it says, “However, it does not appear to be Tor Browser. Click here to go to the download page.”

Comment: Go to the App Store on your iPad. Tap on the search icon at the bottom (magnifying glass) type: Onion Browser, tap on the top selection in the list. The first selection (for me) is called "Onion Browser" with a black and purple icon. Get that. It is a TorBrowser for the App store based on the TorBrowser code

Comment: @Ms.Bunny You can use this link to download Onion Browser from the App Store on your iPad. It is available free of cost: https://itunes.apple.com/app/onion-browser/id519296448#?platform=ipad